# Basic Implementation of a Stack

Tags: c

```
int pop(STA* stack)
{
    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        return stack->array[stack->top--] ;
    return '$';
}
```

What is the useage of the (return'$') in this function?
What kind of value will it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's just default return value in case stack is empty (which should not really happen, precondition of calling `pop()` should be for stack not to be empty. )

It will return 36 ( code of `$` )

Answer (score 2):

Will return the number of '$' in ascii table (36)

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it. What ASCII value will it return?

Comment: Search for ascii table, if you do `printf("%c", 36)` you will print the '$'

Answer (score 2):

It will return 36, the ASCII value of the'$' sign.

Answer (score 2):

The implementor of this stack module has decided that upon an empty stack, the return value will be `$`, or integer value 36.

It means the stack can/will never contain an integer value 36. If it would, the return value due to empty stack is indistinguishable from a valid return of value 36.

For this stack module, the caller should always call `isEmpty()` before trying to pop from the stack (or ensure the stack will never contain the value 36).

Comment: Actually, the return value `42` would be a better choice :-)